# How to create Excel Table by VBA at runtime?

Tags: vba, excel

During execution of macro I reads multiple excel file and creates a new excel file, i build a similar sheet:

[image]

At runtime by VBA I want to set this area and create a table, add Total Row and get the following result:

[image]

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Range("A1:I9").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$I$9"), , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ShowTotals = True
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("B").TotalsCalculation = xlTotalsCalculationSum
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("C").TotalsCalculation = xlTotalsCalculationSum
'Repeat row above until column I
```

I got this by recording a VBA Macro. If you are not familiar with Macro recording see link [here](http://www.analystcave.com/tutorials/excel-vba-tutorial/#Excel_VBA_Tutorial_Recording_Macros).